# Overflow hidden does not work with dingbat font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to make text overflow being hidden in a `td` element on the page
using a [custom dingbat font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/im-fell-flowers-1?q%5Bterm%5D=wedding&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y).

For some reason when I set `overflow:hidden;` the text simply disappears.
When I remove the font-face declaration, it works as expected.

I also notice that the font itself is shifted down in markup, which is not the problem for me, but it feels like a browser has hard time rendering it?

Here is the [live preview](http://codepen.io/gogromat/pen/JYmdzN?editors=110).

Update:
As suggested by Stephen Thomas I tried running this example on different machines, and on Windows Vista it looks great on all major browsers (as far as I can tell). And it works for him on Mac OS. But it doesn't work well for me on Linux :s.
Also this custom font is *shifted down* on many browsers.

Comment: the live preview looks fine to me. Safari 9.0.1 on OS X 10.11.1

Comment: hmmm, that's weird, I tried browserling with Windows Vista, and all browsers work fine. I however use Linux and Chromium 46 does not work. Firefox on Linux also works...